# Microsoft Excel copy paste to Powerpoint, both files crashing

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following VBA code where I am copying an excel range to Powerpoint. I have played around with adding various delays to ensure the copy paste command is executed correctly, however the file crashed regardless of the delay.

I currently have a `Do loop` and the file still crashes without exiting the loop. If somebody could provide some guidance, it will be greatly appreciated

```
rng.Copy
DoEvents

Do
    On Error Resume Next
    mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteBitmap  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
    Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
    'Set position:
    myShape.Left = 50
    myShape.Top = 141
    myShape.Width = 620
    myShape.Height = 320

    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        On Error GoTo 0
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: Take out the error handler - does it throw any errors? If so, which one(s) and where?

Comment: There are two, On Error Resume Next, or in the If Err.Number statement?

Comment: in case of error your code goes to infinite loop and then stack overflow literally:)

Comment: What happens if you add `DoEvents` after every paste statement as well? i.e after the line `mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteBitmap`. Also if you are latebinding, have you set the value of `ppPasteBitmap `?

Comment: No I have not. Let me get back to you with the error because now it seems to be running without any problems. So let me try multiple scenarios that might cause the program to fail so I will be able to provide more details regarding the error.

Comment: If it is working fine now then I guess the `DoEvents` trick just might help you...

Comment: try to change `ppPasteBitmap` to `ppPasteEnhancedMetafile`?

Comment: I will try that winghei, Siddrhat the problem is it runs fine for a bit and then will sporadically start crashing. So not a total foolproof method yet

Comment: @Raptor776 test my code below, I export all my Excel Ranges to PowerPoint Slides with this method

Comment: Did you even try the suggestion that I gave?

Comment: @Siddharth so keeping the rest of the code the same, and adding the line DoEvents after mySlide.Shapes.Past‌​eSpecial ppPasteBitmap didnt make a difference

Comment: Did it crash after inserting that line?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you declared and set-up `mySlide` correctly to your desired slide, use the following code:

```
Dim myShape                             As Object

Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteBitmap)

'Set position:
myShape.Left = 50
myShape.Top = 141
myShape.Width = 620
myShape.Height = 320
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try this piece of code. Right now the old code somehow seems to be running fine. But I will build this code into the next revision for more robustness.